# Click on the category list and get products using category id in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, intel-xdk

I am using Intelxdk for this application. This is a mobile application.

My categorylist will show, after that click on that, I have to redirect the product page, When I click on the category I can get some error like this. "Can't find variable: $state".

**CategoryController.js**

```
app.controller('CategoryController', ['$scope','getServices','JSONDataService', function($scope,getServices,JSONDataService) {

 var url = 'http://look4what.biz/mobile/shop-category.php';

$scope.getId = function(termid){
JSONDataService.addTansferData(termid);
    $state.go('/:id');

}
 getServices.sendRequest(url)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {


 $scope.userslists = data;


 })
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });

}]);
```

---

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('LookApp', ['ionic','ngCordova','ngRoute','paymentCtrls']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$routeProvider) {
$routeProvider 

.when('/', {
controller: 'CategoryController',
templateUrl: 'views/category.html'
 })

.when('/:id', {
controller: 'ProductController',
templateUrl: 'views/users.html'
})

.when('/login/:friendId', {
controller: 'LoginController',
templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
})

.otherwise({
redirectTo: '/'
});


});
```

---

**ProductController.js**

```
app.controller('ProductController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'category','JSONDataService','getServices', function($scope, $routeParams, category,JSONDataService,getServices) {

$scope.newData = JSONDataService.getTansferData();

term_id="+$scope.newData;

var url = "http://look4what.biz/mobile/id-get-detail.php?term_id="+termid;

getServices.sendRequest(url)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
 $scope.userslists = data;

})

.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    });

}]);
```

Comment: In `CategoryController` you need do dependency injection. Like this `app.controller('CategoryController', ['$scope','getServices','JSONDataService','$state', function($scope,getServices,JSONDataService,$state)...`

Comment: Now, I can see this error Could not resolve '/:id' from state ''

How to fix it

Comment: Read [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) for `$state`. Try  `$state.go('id',termid)`.

Comment: I went through this document but, I can't fix it.
please, can you help me.